# My hometown is 'situated near London' or 'situated near from London'?

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence.

> My hometown is situated near **from** London

Do I actually need to use the *from* here? Or I could just say

> My hometown is situated near London.

Comment: My hometown is situated near London. No need for preposition.

Comment: @Khan What's wrong with the stated?

Comment: @DmitryBundin "My hometown is stated near London" makes no sense; in fact, I'm not even clear what you're *trying* to say with that sentence. Are you trying to say "my hometown is located near London," or are you trying to say "people often say that my hometown is located near London?"

Comment: The word 'near' is already a preposition.

Comment: Sander, you are right. It doesn't need another preposition.

Comment: *My hometown is near London* and *My hometown is close to London* sound much more natural than using *situated*. Instead of *situated*, try *located*. You could also say *My hometown is not far from London*.

Comment: Or "my hometown is a short distance from London".

Answer (score 4):

If you were going to use a preposition, you would use:

> My house is situated near **to** London.

Otherwise, no preposition is needed.

Comment: Just to confirm, *near to* is a prepositional phrase, isn't it?

Comment: @XPMai **Near to London** is _technically_ the preposition; but yes you are correct.